# Max signal per seconds

Tags: unix, ipc, signals

I would like to know how many signal per second (or any time ratio) a program can catch.
The problem is that I want to receive signal them 8 per 8 to fill a char (with sigusr1 for '0' and sigusr2 for '1') And when I don't use sleep-like function the program send "User signal 1 or 2" and then exit.

Is there anyway to determine how many signal a program can catch ?
With my test it depends of the sequence duration ( for 100 digits he'll not miss a single one but over 500 he start to miss some of them, I use usleep(1000) between each transmission.

Thanks you.

EDIT: Sorry sending it too soon.

Comment: Using signals to communicate data like this is an appalling idea.  You can tell your teaching staff that I said so - but you might not win many friends by actually doing it.  Signals are intended for rare occurrences - not high-density communication.

Comment: Thanks you for the advice, but I'm really looking forward to use signals

Comment: If you run into reliability problems, treat it as the noisy channel that it is, and work out a protocol for error correcting for missed signals (bits) or misinterpreted bits (probably caused by missing a signal), and perhaps a way of acknowledging to the sender where the receiver is in the processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on many variables -- the hardware, the load of the machine due to other software running, etc.  There is no way you can tune sleep times to be reliable in all circumstances.  External signals are inherently asynchronous.

Basically, you're using signals in a way they weren't intended to be used.  For communication of bulk data there are much better IPC choices, from simple pipes to D-Bus with elaborate rendezvous, multicast and filtering capabilities layered on top of sockets.

Comment: Thanks you I guess I'm just gonna vehicle a token over the communication that avoid me taking another solution!